# Why does ActiveSupport add method forty_two to Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

You can see the method [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb#L53).

Is this a joke?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/823os/rails_core_has_a_method_for_accessing_the_reddit/

Comment: @Abdo OP is having good eyes.. What a post.. Valid Q for me :-)

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e50530ca3ab5db53ebc74314c54b62b91b932389 useful

Comment: Here is your food http://confreaks.com/videos/431-rubyconf2010-keynote-why-ruby, enjoy it ;-)

Answer (score 24):

I think `Array#forty_two` is a quite clever and convenient way to fetch a really important element from an array. An element that might answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Well one question only,